# How to provide schema in spark/scala from outside the code

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to read a file for ex: **schema_file** which will contain the schema and want to use it in code for creating `DataFrame`

I have read about `ConfigFactory` to provide schema but can't use it as the schema could be changed in future .

```
schema[
  {
     columnName = EXAMPLE_1
     type = string
  },
  {
     columnName = EXAMPLE_2
     type = string
  },
  {
     columnName = EXAMPLE_3
     type = string
  }
]
```

if I use this than i have to read every columnName like

```
    config.getString("schema.ColumnName1")
```

but the columns are not fixed and the no of columns can be changed.

Also i tried using **case class** but in that as well i need to specify each and every field.

Can anyone tell me how can i read schema from outside the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this library to load configuration and map it into scala classes: https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig

I hope something like that will work for you:

```
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.syntactical.StandardTokenParsers

object Application extends App {
  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fileContents = Source.fromFile("src/main/resources/schema_file").getLines.mkString
    print(ConfigDSL.parseSchema(fileContents))
  }
}

case class Schema(columns: List[Column])
case class Column(columnName: String, columnType: String)

object ConfigDSL extends StandardTokenParsers {
  lexical.delimiters ++= List("[", "]", "{", "}", ",", " ", "=", "\n")
  lexical.reserved ++= List("schema", "type", "columnName")

  def parseSchema(schemaString: String): Schema = 
    schema(new lexical.Scanner(schemaString)) match {
      case Success(columns, _) => Schema(columns)
      case Failure(msg, _) => throw new RuntimeException(msg)
      case Error(msg, _) => throw new RuntimeException(msg)
    }

  def schema: Parser[List[Column]] =
    "schema" ~ "[" ~ listOfColumns ~ "]" ^^ { case _ ~ _ ~ recipeList ~ _ => recipeList }

  def columnDefinition: Parser[Column] =
    "{" ~ "columnName" ~ "=" ~ ident ~ "type" ~ "=" ~ ident ~ "}" ^^ {
      case _ ~ _ ~ _ ~ column ~ _ ~ _ ~ columnType ~ _ => Column(column, columnType)
    }

  def listOfColumns: Parser[List[Column]] =
    repsep(columnDefinition, ",")  ^^ { stepList: List[Column] => stepList}
}
```

Comment: I would like to suggest that another possibility would be to make your _schema_ a **JSON** and loading it using [Circe](https://circe.github.io/circe/) - @sheetalkaur in both cases you would end with a case class that represents your _schema_, and you can later traverse it to create the _schema_ of your data.

Comment: I am using XML file to create dataframe and while creating , it expects schema to be of StructType therefore i am not able to use case class.                                 Need to use StructType to specify schema

Comment: @sheetalkaur, ok, you can also create simple parser for your config. Answer updated.